# How to use summation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a randomly generated vector, say `A` of length `M`.

Say:

```
A = rand(M,1)
```

And I also have a function, `X(k) = sin(2*pi*k)`.

How would I find `Y(k)` which is summation of `A(l)*X(k-l)` as `l` goes from 0 to `M`?

Assume any value of k... But the answer should be summation of all `M+1` terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `M` and `k`, this is how you can perform your summation:

```
A = rand(M+1,1);            %# Create M+1 random values
Y = sin(2*pi*(k-(0:M)))*A;  %# Use a matrix multiply to perform the summation
```

**EDIT:** You could even create a function for `Y` that takes `k` and `A` as arguments:

```
Y = @(k,A) sin(2*pi*(k+1-(1:numel(A))))*A;  %# An anonymous function
result = Y(k,A);                            %# Call the function Y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = rand(1, M + 1);
X = sin(2 * pi * (k - (0 : M)));
total = sum(A .* X);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do a fourier transform, you should also look at fft.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the convolution of the vectors A and X:

```
Y = conv(A, X);
```

Comment: The output `Y` in that case would be a vector of length `2*M+1`, instead of a single value like the OP is looking for. I think one of the values in the vector will be the desired value (the middle value `Y(M+1)`), but there's no sense in computing all the other values too.

Comment: Ah- I sensed some ambiguity when the OP mentioned "Assume any value of k", which is why I mentioned that he/she 'may' be looking for the convolution :-)